# fix the width of the div even if the data is minimal

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I want to fix the width of the chart to 100% even if the data is not available.
I'm using the following properties in my js code to get the horizontal scroll and the below properties are required in my application.

```
"width": chart1.data.rows.length *130,
 "bar": {groupWidth: 40},
```

Below property is used to fix the width,height of the chart, but it is not working as i have used the code mentioned above to calculate and define the width which is required for the horizontal scrollbar display when data is more.

```
  chartArea:{left:20,top:0,width:'100%',height:'75%'}
```

Any suggestions as how to fix the width of the chart to 100% even if the data is minimal?
Please find the demo [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/sLcwv5AAdmq3q7iDOkFE?p=preview)

------Edit----

**when the data is less:**

https://plnkr.co/edit/q0NmXQVXgmnOi3g1WcEx?p=preview - when data is less and width is set using "width": chart1.data.rows.length *130, u can see the chart area is minimized when there is not much data.

https://plnkr.co/edit/VZqEfHdgZQOEzfUnO21G?p=preview - width is set to 100%.this is what i want my chart to be like even when the data is less but if i use width:"100%", when the data is more it wont show horizontal scrollbar as shown in https://plnkr.co/edit/iIVfF4rUv0c13SLaNMkr?p=preview

**when data is more:**

https://plnkr.co/edit/3kZR69VMSjFcBHUaCnB9?p=preview - when data is more and width is set to 100%, horizontal scrollbar is not displayed.

https://plnkr.co/edit/iIVfF4rUv0c13SLaNMkr?p=preview - when data is more and width is set using "width": chart1.data.rows.length *130, you can notice a horizontal scrollbar down to page where you can scroll and see the data.

Comment: Try `"width": chart1.data.rows.length ? chart1.data.rows.length*130 : 200`, where 200 is some minimal width.

Comment: @skobaljic - no luck..Please find link https://plnkr.co/edit/Frupn9vgSk1gN5Dx0BMX?p=preview

Comment: That one works fine, show me the one that does not work?

Comment: @skobaljic - https://plnkr.co/edit/Frupn9vgSk1gN5Dx0BMX?p=preview , in this link i have added the code you suggested "width": chart1.data.rows.length ? chart1.data.rows.length*130 : 200 and still the width is not 100%.I want the graph as shown in https://plnkr.co/edit/VfSYVqQ4Zamj5iDGCYuU?p=preview , but this is achieved after commenting "width": chart1.data.rows.length *130, which is required in my application.

Comment: Hehe, just use `"width": "100%",` instead... you can delete the question after, cheers, plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/a3DvnLG64Jo9sNPp87MN?p=preview)

Comment: Only other option is to find a treshold for when you need "chart1.data.rows.length*130 " and evaluating it to the rows.length and writing the condition based on that. "width": (chart1.data.rows.length > 2) ? chart1.data.rows.length*130 : 2000    Else, only option is to use "width:100%" as @skobaljic suggested

Comment: @VijayMenon - I cannot use "width":"100%" because it wont give scrollbar when the data is more.

Comment: Be creative man, try `"width": chart1.data.rows.length>4 ? chart1.data.rows.length*130 : "100%"`... or be accurate and compare to window width... etc.

Comment: Hope @skobaljic's answer below provides a resolution. Please let us know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not set the chart width, than it will take the width of parent element, which is 100%, as stated in [docs](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_customizing_chart):

> One very common option to set is the chart height and width. You can
>   specify the chart size in two places: in the HTML of the container
>    element, or in the chart options. If you specify the size in
>   both locations, the chart will generally defer to the size specified
>   in the HTML. If you don't specify a chart size either in the HTML or
>   as an option, the chart might not be rendered properly.

In case your calculated, suggested width is larger than window width, than you can add it as:

```
var suggestedWidth = chart1.data.rows.length*130;
if( window.innerWidth<suggestedWidth ) {
  chart1.options.width = suggestedWidth;
};
```

See 2 examples: [first](https://plnkr.co/edit/7u9udnAzv06rgzb8IUIF?p=preview) and [second](https://plnkr.co/edit/JFB6iBESlpNRRob0c4s7?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['googlechart']);

app.controller('myController', function ($scope) {
    var chart1 = {};
    chart1.type = "LineChart";
    chart1.displayed = false;
    chart1.data = {
        "cols": [{
            id: "month",
            label: "Month",
            type: "string"
      }, {
            id: "laptop-id",
            label: "Laptop",
            type: "number"
      }, {
            id: "desktop-id",
            label: "Desktop",
            type: "number"
      }, {
            id: "server-id",
            label: "Server",
            type: "number"
      }, {
            id: "cost-id",
            label: "Shipping",
            type: "number"
      }],
        "rows": [{
            c: [{
                v: "January"
        }, {
                v: 19,
                f: "42 items"
        }, {
                v: 12,
                f: "Ony 12 items"
        }, {
                v: 7,
                f: "7 servers"
        }, {
                v: 4
        }]
      }, {
            c: [{
                    v: "October"
          }, {
                    v: 34
          }, {
                    v: 4
          }, {
                    v: 0
          }, {
                    v: 1
          }

        ]
      }]
    };
    chart1.options = {

        "title": "Sales per month",
        "colors": ['#0000FF', '#009900', '#CC0000', '#DD9900'],
        "defaultColors": ['#0000FF', '#009900', '#CC0000', '#DD9900'],
        "isStacked": "true",
        "fill": 20,
        focusTarget: 'category',
        "displayExactValues": true,
        "vAxis": {
            "title": "Sales unit",
            "gridlines": {
                "count": 10
            }
        },
        "hAxis": {
            "title": "Date"
        },
        /*"width": chart1.data.rows.length *130,*/
        "width": chart1.data.rows.length ? chart1.data.rows.length * 130 : 2000,
        "bar": {
            groupWidth: 40
        },
        chartArea: {
            left: 20,
            top: 0,
            width: '100%',
            height: '75%'
        }
    };
    chart1.view = {
        columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
    };
    $scope.myChart = chart1;

});
```

```html
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.18/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
  
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-google-chart/0.1.0/ng-google-chart.js"></script>
  <title>Angular-Google-Charts Example</title>
</head>

<body>
 
<div ng-controller="myController">
      <div google-chart chart="myChart"></div> 
 </div>
  
</body>

</html>
```